# VB 2010 - A variable with a value of a label name

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VB 2010 Express and have a label named "lblTitle" in my form.
The next code doesn't work and I know it , but how can I do something like this?

```
Dim bla As String
bla = "lblTitle"
bla.Text = "Hello world"
```

Edit: I want to access a label properties without actually having its name.
I get its name from a text file.

Edit 2: Thanks you all guys!
After googling this function you've mentioned I got it:

```
   Dim bla = "lblName"
   Me.Controls(bla).Text = "Dan"
```

While "lblName" is a label's name in the form.

Comment: What do you want to do? What is your intention?

Comment: Edited my question. Is my intention clear now?

Comment: After going deep with google, let's say that "bla" is the variable:

Me.Controls("lbl" & bla).Text

Comment: Can you not just do me.lblTitle.text = "helloWorld"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a deep google search , the answer seems to be easy as that:

```
   Dim bla = "lblName"
   Me.Controls(bla).Text = "Dan"
```

while `lblName` is the label's name in the form.
Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim myLabel As Label = DirectCast(Page.FindControl("lblTitle"), Label)
myLabel.Text = "some new value"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this assuming you are using windows forms:

```
DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("lblTitle", True)(0), Label).Text = "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectCast(Page.FindControl("lblTitle"), Label).Text = "some new value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the best way to do this is to make a string representing the name of the control, then cast it as a control.  This saves you having to make a variable, as well.  Your method might appear to work, but I'm not sure it wouldn't fail once you run it.  Also, it would throw an error in the IDE if you were trying to access a property more specific to the type of control, and not something common like Text.    See my closely related question:

[accessing multiple form controls using a variable for the name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711844/1411373)