# accessing multiple form controls using a variable for the name

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb.net-2010, vb6-migration

I'm trying to iterate through a group of ComboBoxes and set a property using a concatenated string & variable to represent the name of the control.  However, I can't get the instance of the form to recognize the (String & Integer_Variable) as one of its controls -- and so it doesn't recognize any of the appropriate properties or subroutines as members of the System.Windows.Forms.Control.

I found the [DirectCast solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8015094/1411373) and it appears to work (although I'm dubious), but that feels like a very clumsy solution.  Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```vb
For myTempCount = 1 To 6
    If tempValue < Me.("ComboBox" & myTempCount).Items.Count Then
        ComboBox.SelectedIndex = tempValue 'appears to work -- how?
        Me.ComboBox.SelectedIndex = tempValue 'appears to work

        Me.("ComboBox" & myTempCount).SelectedIndex = tempValue 'doesn't work
        Me.Controls.("ComboBox" & myTempCount).SelectedIndex = tempValue 'doesn't work

        DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find(("ComboBox" & myTempCount), True)(0), ComboBox).SelectedIndex = tempValue 'appears to work
        DirectCast(Me.Controls("ComboBox" & myTempCount), ComboBox).SelectedIndex = tempValue  'appears to work
Next
```

This code was originally VBA / VB6, which I put through ArtinSoft's Visual Basic Upgrade Companion (VBUC).  FWIW, I'm using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex` works because ComboBox1 is the control that is present in the Form's ControlCollection
2. `Me.ComboBoxPrinter1.SelectedIndex` works because Me is a reference to your Form class an it is referencing the Control.
3. `Me.("ComboBoxPrinter" & myTempCount).SelectedIndex` doesn't work because the string `ComboBoxPrinter & myTempCount` is a string not a Control.
4. `Me.Controls.("ComboBoxPrinter" & myTempCount).SelectedIndex` doesn't work for the same reasons.
5. The other two instances work because you are using the string as a key to lookup and return the control which you the cast to the proper type and set your property.

I personally usually use CType other than DirectCast. The main difference according to this [link](http://www.novicksoftware.com/TipsAndTricks/tip-visual-basic-ctype-directcast-dot-net.htm) between CType and DirectCast is that DirectCast has to be the exact Type where as CType can be used in narrowing or widening Conversions. DirectCast is more effiecent albeit more finicky.

That being said you could do something like this:

```
For myTempCount = 1 To 6
    If Controls.ContainsKey("ComboBox" & myTempCount) Then
        CType(Controls("ComboBox" & myTempCount), ComboBox).SelectedIndex = tempValue
    End If
Next
```

I am not using Me in front of Controls since it refers to the same collection, if your controls are in another collection you will need to use that Container instead. i.e. if you were using a Panel `Panel1.Controls.ContainsKey`

Answer (score 0):

Ouch!!! I messed with Direct Cast once.  I remember it being a nightmare.  My preference is to either stick with server side controls, or write them in as client side Javascript/Ajax.  Where at in your above code is it failing?  Any inner exceptions?

Comment: Sorry you saw that, it wasn't supposed to be in that form, I accidentally posted while I was still drafting the question. =)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this (C#):

```
List<Control> comboBoxes = new List<Control>
{
   ComboBoxPrinter1,
   ComboBoxPrinter2,
   ComboBoxPrinter3,
   ComboBoxPrinter4,
   ComboBoxPrinter5,
   ComboBoxPrinter6
};

// loop through combo boxes collection by position
for (int = 0; i < comboBoxes.Length;i++)
{
    // put in your if logic here, and refer to current combo box using comboBoxes[i]
}
```

Here is the above code converted to VB.NET using online tool:

```
Dim comboBoxes As New List(Of Control)() From { _
    ComboBoxPrinter1, _
    ComboBoxPrinter2, _
    ComboBoxPrinter3, _
    ComboBoxPrinter4, _
    ComboBoxPrinter5, _
    ComboBoxPrinter6 _
}

For i As Integer = 0 To comboBoxes.Count - 1
  // you can hook in your if logic and refer to each combo box using comboBoxes[i]
Next
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: That would work, but I'm trying to avoid listing the full control names somewhere, as this sort of iteration happens elsewhere in the code.

Comment: I had a feeling you would say that :)  In that case, I would extract that line that defines the list of controls into its own method, so you can use it from multiple places.  I hope you find it a somewhat elegant way to reduce duplication and make maintaining the code easier :)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue again with multiple controls of differing types that needed the same operation performed on a common property (like `.Text`).  Since you cannot use a variable to represent the control type parameter in `CType()`, you'll have to use a conditional and a corresponding hardcoded `CType()` command to get the control.  This is what I came up with:

```vb
Function getControl(ByVal controlName As String) As Control
    numCtrls = FrameMain.Controls.Count()
    For I As Integer = 0 To numCtrls - 1
        If FrameMain.Controls.Item(I).Name = controlName Then
            If TypeOf FrameMain.Controls.Item(I) Is ComboBox Then
                Return CType(FrameMain.Controls(controlName), ComboBox)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

`controlName` is the concatenated string name.  So, you can use this Function pretty much the same way the previous answers used `CType()`:

```
getControl("TextBox" & myTempCount).Text = "whatever"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim control As Control = Me.Controls("Button1")
    Select Case control.GetType
        Case GetType(Button)
            Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(control, Button)
            With btn
                .Text = "hi"
            End With
        Case GetType(Label)
            Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(control, Label)
            With lbl
                .Text = "hi"
            End With
        Case Else 'etc
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Button2Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'For i = 1 To 5
    If textBox15_08_St.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Bitte die Anzahl eintragen!","Info",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If dataGridView15_08.SelectedRows.Count = 0 And dataGridView15_08.SelectedCells.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Bitte eine Zeile auswählen","Info",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Exit Sub    
    End If

    If dataGridView15_08.SelectedRows.Count > 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Bitte nur 1 Zeile auswählen!","Info",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub    
    End If  
    
    If dataGridView15_08.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Bitte Filter überprüfen!","Info",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Exit Sub    
    End If
    
Dim i As Integer = 1

For Each c As CheckBox In panelCheckBox.Controls

Dim BoxName As String = "checkBox15_08_" & Str(i)
Dim CheckName As String = "checkBox15_08_" & Str(i)

BoxName = BoxName.Replace(" ", "")

    If c.Name = BoxName Then

        If c.Checked = False Then
            
            c.Checked = True

        CType(Me.panelCheckBox.Controls(CheckName.Replace(" ","")), CheckBox).Enabled = True
        CType(Me.panelTextbox.Controls(BoxName.Replace("checkBox15_08","Hersteller15")), TextBox).Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView15_08.Rows(dataGridView15_08.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(1).Value)
        CType(Me.panelTextbox.Controls(BoxName.Replace("checkBox15_08","Artikel15")), TextBox).Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView15_08.Rows(dataGridView15_08.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(3).Value)
        CType(Me.panelTextbox.Controls(BoxName.Replace("checkBox15_08","Artikel_St_15")), TextBox).Text = Me.textBox15_08_St.Text
        textBox15_08_St.Text = ""
        Exit For
        Else
            If CType(Me.panelTextbox.Controls(BoxName.Replace("checkBox15_08","Hersteller15")), TextBox).Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView15_08.Rows(dataGridView15_08.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(1).Value) _
                And CType(Me.panelTextbox.Controls(BoxName.Replace("checkBox15_08","Artikel15")), TextBox).Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView15_08.Rows(dataGridView15_08.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(3).Value) Then
                
                MessageBox.Show("Dieser Artikel wurde bereits hinzugefügt","Info",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                Exit For    
                
            End If
        End If
    End If
    i = i+1
    If i = 31 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Die maximale Anzahl wurde erreicht" & vbCrLf & "Bitte setze Dich mit dem Programierer in Verbindung" & vbCrLf & "Um ein Update Erweiterung zu planen","Info",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit For    
    End If  
Next

'End For
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_1.Click
checkBox15_08_1.Checked = Me.getControl(1)
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_2Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_2.Click 
checkBox15_08_2.Checked = Me.getControl(2) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_3Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_3.Click 
checkBox15_08_3.Checked = Me.getControl(3) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_4Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_4.Click 
checkBox15_08_4.Checked = Me.getControl(4) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_5Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_5.Click 
checkBox15_08_5.Checked = Me.getControl(5) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_6Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_6.Click 
checkBox15_08_6.Checked = Me.getControl(6) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_7Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_7.Click 
checkBox15_08_7.Checked = Me.getControl(7) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_8Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_8.Click 
checkBox15_08_8.Checked = Me.getControl(8) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_9Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_9.Click 
checkBox15_08_9.Checked = Me.getControl(9) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_10Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_10.Click 
checkBox15_08_10.Checked = Me.getControl(10) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_11Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_11.Click 
checkBox15_08_11.Checked = Me.getControl(11) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_12Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_12.Click 
checkBox15_08_12.Checked = Me.getControl(12) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_13Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_13.Click 
checkBox15_08_13.Checked = Me.getControl(13) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_14Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_14.Click 
checkBox15_08_14.Checked = Me.getControl(14) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_15Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_15.Click 
checkBox15_08_15.Checked = Me.getControl(15) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_16Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_16.Click 
checkBox15_08_16.Checked = Me.getControl(16) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_17Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_17.Click 
checkBox15_08_17.Checked = Me.getControl(17) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_18Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_18.Click 
checkBox15_08_18.Checked = Me.getControl(18) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_19Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_19.Click 
checkBox15_08_19.Checked = Me.getControl(19) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_20Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_20.Click 
checkBox15_08_20.Checked = Me.getControl(20) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_21Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_21.Click 
checkBox15_08_21.Checked = Me.getControl(21) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_22Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_22.Click 
checkBox15_08_22.Checked = Me.getControl(22) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_23Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_23.Click 
checkBox15_08_23.Checked = Me.getControl(23) 
End Sub
Sub checkBox15_08_24Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_24.Click 
checkBox15_08_24.Checked = Me.getControl(24) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_25Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_25.Click 
checkBox15_08_25.Checked = Me.getControl(24) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_26Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_26.Click
checkBox15_08_26.Checked = Me.getControl(26) 
End Sub
Sub checkBox15_08_27Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_27.Click 
checkBox15_08_27.Checked = Me.getControl(27) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_28Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_28.Click 
checkBox15_08_28.Checked = Me.getControl(28) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_29Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_29.Click 
checkBox15_08_29.Checked = Me.getControl(29) 
End Sub

Sub checkBox15_08_30Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkBox15_08_30.Click 
checkBox15_08_30.Checked = Me.getControl(30) 
End Sub

Function getControl(ByVal controlName As Integer) As Boolean
    
    Dim txt_Name1 As String = "Hersteller15_" & Str(controlName)
    Dim txt_Name2 As String = "Artikel15_" & Str(controlName)
    Dim txt_Name3 As String = "Artikel_St_15_" & Str(controlName)
    Dim CheckName As String = "checkBox15_08_" & Str(controlName)

If CType(Me.panelCheckBox.Controls(CheckName.Replace(" ","")), CheckBox).Enabled = True Then

    CType(Me.panelCheckBox.Controls(CheckName.Replace(" ","")), CheckBox).Enabled = False
    MessageBox.Show(txt_Name1)
        
    CType(Me.panelTextbox.Controls(txt_Name1.Replace(" ", "")), TextBox).Text = ""
    CType(Me.panelTextbox.Controls(txt_Name2.Replace(" ", "")), TextBox).Text = ""
    CType(Me.panelTextbox.Controls(txt_Name3.Replace(" ", "")), TextBox).Text = ""
    
    End If
Return False
    
End Function

'doesn't work without the command Replace(" ", ""))
'That has to be adjusted!
'Me.Controls(txt_Name1.Replace(" ", "")), TextBox).Text = "whatever"
'Me.panelCheckBox.Controls(txt_Name1.Replace(" ", "")), TextBox).Text = "whatever"
'Me.GroupBox1.Controls(txt_Name1.Replace(" ", "")), TextBox).Text = "whatever"
```