# variable with a value of a control

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5

I have a problem similar to [Variable with Value of a Label Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015094/vb-2010-a-variable-with-a-value-of-a-label-name)

But instead of a label, I am trying to use a ListBox

```
    Private Sub processLog(ByVal logFileName As String, ByVal logCateory As String)
    Dim variableListBox As New ListBox

    variableListBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls(logCateory), ListBox)
    variableListBox.Items.Add("HELLO")

    End Sub
```

What could possible be wrong with the above code, it return `NullReferenceException was unhandled` `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the line, `variableListBox.Items.Add("HELLO")`.

I have also a timer to call the above `Sub`:

```
    Private Sub tmrProcessLogs_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrProcessLogs.Tick
       processLog(fileGeneral, lbxGeneral.Name.ToString)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Probably there's no control named `logCateory` in the container, a debugger could help you to find the exact problem.

Comment: the `logCategory` is the variable use to pass the name of the control. When the timer ticks, a `sub` is called with parameters in which the second parameter is the name of the `control`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the parent of the given control is not the `Main Form` and, as far as `Me.Controls("name")` only looks for controls whose parent is the Main Form, `variableListBox` is `Nothing` and thus you trigger the error while intending to access `Items.Add("HELLO")`. Replace

```
variableListBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls(logCateory), ListBox)
variableListBox.Items.Add("HELLO")
```

With:

```
Dim ctrls() As Control = Me.Controls.Find(logCateory, True)
If (ctrls.Count = 1 AndAlso TypeOf ctrls(0) Is ListBox) Then
     variableListBox = DirectCast(ctrls(0), ListBox)
     variableListBox.Items.Add("HELLO")
End If
```

All this by assuming that `logCateory` contains the name of one of the controls in the form (a parent or a child at any level).

Comment: the same error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @PaulPolon This is impossible. This code avoids this to happen (even in case of not finding any control called logCateory). Please, post the code you have tried. It might not find anything but variableListBox =... is only reached in case of finding the right control and thus the error you refer will never be triggered (it might be the case that nothing happens)